# Return the first 3 matches using regular expression

Tags: regex

Today I was teaching a guy about regular expressions. We had a block of text that contains any sort of character, and we were doing some example on it. At some point, he asked me how to catch only the first three characters that match our expression. As example, we have random text that contains multiple "3" and we what an expression that matches only the first three, but not the others

> dsasd **3**2 errsasdfdsfdfsdfdsf sdfsdfsdfsfsdfsdf
>   sdfsdf**3**sdfsdfsdffsdf**3**sdfsdfsdfs3

I didn't know how to do it since I always did it using a function and not the regular expressions language. I was wondering if is possible to do it using only regular expressions itself.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what exactly you're looking for. Do you need the regex to **match** the first 3 occurrences of `3` or return them from capturing groups? What's the point of having a regex function that returns literal strings you've already defined?

Comment: Yes, my question was how can I write a regular expression that **match** the first 3 occurrences of '3'. The point was to use the logic of this to **match**  the first 3 strings that match this syntax **\d+,\d{2}**. This is a string that match amounts inside an invoice

Comment: So you don't need it to return any captured strings? Simply matching a pattern returns a boolean, in which case it doesn't matter whether or not there are more than 3 occurrences, because you'd never see the difference. Like `3.*3.*3` will match, but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: @Thefourthbird fourth bird isn't this matching the whole thing?

Comment: @CAustin your syntax is matching the characters between the 3. We are looking for a syntax that matches only the 3

Comment: You can't individually match the `3`s, unless you enable a global modifier, in which case it will match all of them. You'd have to use a function that loops 3 times if you don't want to match everything in between.

Comment: @Thefourthbird using your syntax with https://regex101.com/library highlight all this string 'eeeeeeeeeeeeese3dsdddddddd3eeeeeeeeeeeeeee3'

Comment: @Thefourthbird That's why I asked if he just wanted a plain match, as opposed to capturing groups. He says he just wants a match, which isn't possible using only regex.

Comment: @CAustin Yes, I think that looping a function is a right way to do it. Just wondering if something like this could work, actually isn't working and I not figuring why '(?<=[^3])3(?<=[^3]3[^3])3(?<=[^3]3[^3]3[^3])3'

Comment: That will match 3 consecutive `3`s not adjacent to `3`. So, logically impossible.

Comment: Ok sir, I will move forward to the use of the functions. Thanks for your time

Comment: It is very easy with a .NET/PyPi Python `regex` regex libraries (or Vim, too). Just use `(?<![^3]*(?:3[^3]*){3})3`